# Store Teamcity Build Steps in Branch

Tags: configuration, teamcity

Whenever we change a Teamcity build definition (e.g. to use a new version of the NUnit console runner), it breaks the builds if we need to hotfix an earlier version of our code. To address this, I'd like to store the build definition alongside the code, so that it executes the build as it looked at the time the hotfix is branched from.

I've been looking into exporting the TC build definitions as Kotlin scripts, but I have a couple of issues with them:

- `Versioned Settings` is controlled by a higher-level project I don't have access to, and is stored in a separate repository (and not as Kotlin).
- It seems like it'll just look at your master branch and import settings from there, but I need the build to use whatever is on my hotfix branch at the point of execution.

In the past, we've solved this with Fake scripts, but the experience tends not to be very good for identifying problems.

What's the best way to execute builds on TeamCity to meet the following requirements?

- Output as close to normal build steps as possible
- Build defined within the branch/code under execution
- Easy to maintain/manage
- Test output should remain the same as in normal TC builds

Answer (score 0):

You can have the TeamCity build configuration automatically stored in your repo. So changes made in the configuration will be committed to master and leaving your configuration on the branch intact. If no usable configuration is found on the branch, the configuration on the master will be used.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/storing-project-settings-in-version-control.html